# Relational SQL Server Databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, html, css

I just registered here and this is my very first question. I hope I can explain myself clearly 'cause being a self-taught developer I don't quite speak the jargon.

My question: my project database holds employee information and has things like firstName, lastName, jobTitle, etc.. (static things).

My problem begins when I want to also start collecting all the clockIn & clockOut events of each employee. I can't think of an elegant way of adding these to my current database.

I don't know too much about databases but I think such things should either go in a totally different database or perhaps in a different table within the same database. 
No idea which is the right answer.

The other thing is that these 2 databases or 2 tables need to somehow relate to each other somehow. When I select an employee from the list [data coming from the 1st DB or Tbl] and choose to view that specific employee's clock event history [data coming from the 2nd DB or Tbl] I should see that employee's clock in's & out's and NOT some other employee's clock events history.

A step-by-step tutorial is not necessary, but appreciated. Can you give me a quick explanation/outline of how this can be done ? If needed, I can add more details about 
the project.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are only interested in developing the database/tables for your app, then I suggest that you remove all the unrelated information about your project. I will edit it now. Approve if you like. Btw, which version of sql server ?

Comment: Thanks "Borat" for the edit but I got the answers I was looking for from "Dai" and "Vikas Rana" so quickly that I didn't get a chance to change it. That is exactly what I needed. So what I should do is just make another table and use a "foreign key" to relate the tables to each other. I guess I can quickly google how to do the foreign key and get this done. Thanks guys! That was super fast! BTW: I tried to vote and it says I have to be up to 15 before I can, so.... sorry.

Comment: no problem. good luck and I wish you `great success` ! Chenqui.

Comment: What a welcome! 2 perfect answers in a couple of minutes. Borat, Dai and Vikas Rana... I owe you. Now I'm on my way to start making that second table. Later.

Comment: While it takes some 'reputation' to upvote you can and should accept one of the answers you are happy with.

Comment: Thanks TaW. I really just didn't think about that. I have to add that both answers (Dai's & Vikas Rana's) were right on. At last I have to pick only one as the right answer, therefor I picked the first one that came in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    EmployeeId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(50),
    LastName nvarchar(50),
    etc
)

CREATE TABLE EmployeeClocks ( -- rename as appropriate
    EmployeeId bigint, -- foreign key
    DateTime datetimeoffset(7),
    ClockInType tinyint, -- values defined by an enum inside your program code

    CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeClocks_Employees FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employees (EmployeeId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Now for some queries:

Getting all of the clock-ins for an employee (assuming `ClockInType = 1` for clock-ins, and `2` for clock-outs):

```
 SELECT
     DateTime
 FROM
     EmployeeClocks
     INNER JOIN Employees ON EmployeeClocks.EmployeeId = Employees.EmployeeId
 WHERE
     Employees.FirstName = "Dick" AND
     Employees.LastName = "Butt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [database schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema)

You have to use two tables in a single database, Dai's answer showed the tables. just adding a few word if you re new to database then first read about it make a design idea than make database. because it very difficult to change in database when project is done.
Read some articles from here

- [database architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214422%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [sql server database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933154%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)